# In React How can I fetch data and render a single object in a states array without mapping the whole thing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a simple fetch call, that maps the data from the state being passed to the state via fetch. I would like to take only a particular object from the items array. By index I suppose. And display its contents. Basically I do not want to loop out all the data. Instead I would like to control when that data gets displayed. like `items[0].name` and `items[0].email` or something like that.

Here is my code and a link to a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-voice-9vjng) for ease of help

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: [],
      isLoaded: false
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          items: json
        });
      });
  }
  render() {
    var { isLoaded, items } = this.state;
    if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    } else {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <ul>
            {items.map(item => (
              <li key={item.id}>
                Name: {item.name} | Email: {item.email}
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: You just have to `filter` the array before rendering; `items.filter((_,i) => i ===  0).map`; `const item = items.findByIndex(0)`; `const item = items[selectedIndex] ?item[selectedIndex] : null`

Comment: findByValue, findByIndex, have you considered such thing, what is your criteria?

Comment: could you show an example?

Comment: If you are talking about `single` object, what are you referring to exactly, is it always the first one `0`th index or is it a particular one that meets certain criteria in which case you would have to rely on `filter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select the value from array using `index` and then display the properties you want to show on UI,

Here i am having a property in state named `index` which is having default value `0`, now on the based on `index` we select the element from `items` array and display it's value

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: [],
      isLoaded: false,
      index: 0
    };
    this.handleIndex = this.handleIndex.bind(this)
  }
  
  handleIndex(event){
    this.setState({index: event.target.value})
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          items: json
        });
      });
  }
  render() {
    var { isLoaded, items, index } = this.state;
    const selected = items [index] || items[0]
    if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    } else {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <ul>
             <li key={selected.id}>
                Name: {selected.name} | Email: {selected.email}
              </li>
          </ul>
          <input type='number' onChange={(e)=>this.handleIndex(e)} placeholder='Enter a valid index'/>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id='root'/>
</body>
```

---

If you need to find `index` based on certain condition then you need to use `findIndex` or also you can use `find` to get required element from array and then display the values, `in case of multiple element can fulfill the condition then you can filter the values first and then`map` over them

Comment: Why would he do that, it's unpredictable, he should filter by some property value

Comment: @EugeneSunic may be you're right, `I would like to take only a particular object from the items array. By index I suppose. And display its contents. Basically I do not want to loop out all the data.` but this line made me think in this way.

Comment: yea I will take this as the answer because while the index won't stay the same I want to know how to do this in general, and when it does I now know to filter instead.

Comment: @CodeManiac could you please look at this question and answer it, I am having trouble using your method for my actual use case. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58526503/how-can-i-filter-json-data-from-api-call-in-react-into-different-sections-of-the

Comment: @Bama i don't see you're using `filter` anywhere in your other question,

Comment: I know I took out my attempts because they were not working. Could you show me the correct way to implement it